# Pydantic defining multiple variables to one field

Tags: python, pydantic

How do I write my `Request` class to say that the payload can be `Union[EcrPayload]` or `Union[S3Payload]`?

```
class EcrPayload(CamelModel):
    repository_name: str
    version: str

class S3Payload(CamelModel):
    bucket_name: str
    object_key_name: str

class Request(CamelModel):
    payload: Union[EcrPayload]
```

Comment: try : payload: Union[EcrPayload, S3Payload]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Union` with both the classes you wish to include:

```py
class Request(CamelModel):
    payload: Union[EcrPayload, S3Payload] # accepts ECR and S3 payloads, but nothing else
```

Note that this means that the member variable `payload` has to be either an instance of `EcrPayload` or `S3Payload`, *but nothing else*.

If you wish to include any type of `CamelModel` instead (including perhaps new models `EcsPayload`, `LambdaPayload` or others that you may define in the future), you can write:

```py
class Request(CamelModel):
    payload: CamelModel # any CamelModel is accepted, including ECR and S3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same CamelModel.

```
class Request(CamelModel):
    payload: Union[CamelModel]
```